# How to add a second password into admin login area of Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to add a second password into admin login area of Wordpress. I don't want to user .htaccess. But i could not find any plugin do that. 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u do it use to way.

i)**Using Plugin.**

ii)**Wp-admin Directory protection using Cpanal Directory.**

I)Try this Plugin

->https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-double-protection/
->https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninjawpass/screenshots/

ii)Read This Article.

->http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-password-protect-your-wordpress-admin-wp-admin-directory/

Enjoy ..!

Comment: Awesome. WP Double Protection is a plugin which i am looking for. Thank you very much.